# Generics in PowerShell 2 not working?

Tags: generics, powershell, powershell-2.0

How could I make a List in PowerShell 2?
I've tried these:

```
[activator]::createinstance(([type]'system.collections.generic.list`1').makegenerictype([string]))
```

and

```
[activator]::createinstance(([type]'system.collections.generic.list`1').makegenerictype([string]))
```

and all I get is just nothing. What's going wrong?

I'm running XP SP3, if it matters

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
PS> $list = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[string]'
PS> $list.Add('foo')
PS> $list
foo

PS> $d = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,datetime]'
PS> $d.Add('moonshot', [datetime]'7/20/1969')
PS> $d['moonshot']

Sunday, July 20, 1969 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: I can't get this one work either, returns nothing. Should it work?

Comment: If you are on PowerShell 2.0 it should.

Comment: Now, I figured out, these attempts were all right, problem was the PS was displaying the data, so it would display nothing, thank you.

Comment: This works except when the generic type resides in a different assembly. Then I get the error 'make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded'. And the type assembly is loaded, a New-Object of the same type works fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you try to create a list based on strings, try this:

```
New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[system.string]'
```

Note that you have to specify 'system.string' (at least on my comp ;) ). If you just use 'string', it throws an exception.

```
[61]: New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[string]'
New-Object : Cannot find type [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:11
+ New-Object <<<<  'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[string]'
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Comment: No luck, I was using this syntax in PowerShell 1, but now it doesn't return anything in PS2, this is the reason why I tried to use the Activator class.

Comment: what does it mean "it doesnt return anything"? what is the error message

Comment: When the collection is empty, it outputs nothing.  Kind of gives you the impression that the new-object failed when in fact it worked.